# Code Igniter Force Download Relative Path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the download helper force_download.

```
function excel()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("import_items.csv");
    $name = 'import_items.csv';
    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

My question is is the path in file_get_contents relative to index.php (it appears to be). Is there a way to make it absolute (is there a CI function to get an absolute path)

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the absolute path of your CI application directory with

```
$real = realpath(APPPATH);
```

then use that to navigate to the absolute path of your CSV.
I don't know if theres any advantage of an absolute over a relative though..

I've never used `file_get_contents` but if it cant open absolute paths then just use `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm aware file_get_contents can't work with absolute paths. It would be relative to the site.

You can specify the full path in the request though

```
file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/files/import_items.csv");
```